# How to localize Behavioral Triggers's cart abandonment email content?

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations

We have implemented the collect.js to use the Behavioral Triggers's cart abandonment.
We are trying to find a way to personalize the email's content language.

I have seen a few articles on how to localize cart abandonment email's products list:

- https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000392817&type=1
- https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_pb_localized_recommendations.htm&type=5
- [Edit behavioural trigger content block: productLink](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/319822/edit-behavioural-trigger-content-block-productlink)

From what I understand, in this article, the localization is only to the CA content block. However, I did not see a way to get the local value so I could personalize email language content.

I did see this article, but it seems like an overkill to make an API call to `recs.igodigital.com` only to get this small info part.

- https://mateuszdabrowski.pl/docs/config/sfmc-behavioral-triggers/#1-ampscript-personalisation

It would have been great if I could access the `contactAttributes` from the collect.js call

```
_etmc.push(["setOrgId", "XXXXX"]);
        _etmc.push(["setUserInfo", {
            "email": user,
            "details": {
                "Local": "EU-en"
            }
        }]);
        _etmc.push(["trackPageView"]);
```

Any advice on how to get this piece of data?

Comment: Remember to mark my answer as accepted if it has been helpful

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is [not possible](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000384417&type=1) to access additional user attributes anywhere outside the [Rule Manager](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_pb_personalization_rule_manager.htm&type=5&language=en_US) - so you will not be able to fetch the locale of your identified visitors to use in emails for localisation.

I would assume that, connected to the ID of the individual contact, you have the language preference/locale in your data model, allowing you to join the ID received in setUserInfo call with this, using either SQL or Ampscript Lookup function in your email.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution that can work for my use case:
Concat the SKU with the `Local` both in Collect.js calls and in the catalog. For the new catalog, it's basically an outer join of the available `Local`s and the old catalog's SKUs.

In the email access the SKU using the following code:

```
%%[
Set @data = Concat('{"trigger_payload":"', data, '"}')
Set @mid = "515010543"
]%%

<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core", "1");
    try {
        var defaults = {
            "link": "Link",
            "image_link": "ImageLink",
            "product_code": "ProductCode",
            "name": "Name",
            "regular_price": "RegularPrice",
            "sale_price": "SalePrice",
            "sku_id": "SkuID"
        };

        // Data from block settings
        var settings = {
            "fields": {
                "image_link": "ImageLink", "name": "ProductName", "description": "Description", "regular_price": "RegularPrice", "sale_price": "SalePrice"
            },
            "maxItems": 4,
            "sortBy": "item_order",
            "sortDirection": "desc",
            "desktopCols": 2,
            "mobileCols": 0,
            "useSalePricing": true
        };


        // Read data from MC
        var data = Platform.Variable.GetValue("@data");
        var mid = Platform.Variable.GetValue("@mid");

        // Build the url
        var protocol = "https";
        var hostname = mid + ".recs.igodigital.com";
        var qs = "?item_count=" + settings["maxItems"] + "&sort_by=" + settings["sortBy"] + "&sort_direction=" + settings["sortDirection"];
        var includes = [];
        for (var key in settings["fields"]) {
            if (defaults[key] == null) {
                includes = includes.concat(settings["fields"][key]);
            }
        }

        if (includes.length > 0) {
            qs += "&include=" + includes.join("|")
        }

        var url = protocol + "://" + hostname + "/" + mid + "/trigger" + qs;

        var result = HTTP.Post(url, "application/json", data, []);
        var response = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(result.Response[0]);


        Write("Local: " + Stringify(response.products[0].sku_id).substring(0, 6) + '<br>');

    } catch (e) {
        Write("Error: " + e);
    }


</script>
```

Now that you have the `Local`, all options are available. You can combine both [Localization](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_pb_localized_recommendations.htm&type=5) and dynamic content in the email.

Note: Only the SKU can be accessed that way, whereas other information that is passed in the collect.js `Track Cart Activity` call, won't be accessible. It looks like MC is using the SKU and getting the rest of the data by matching that in the catalog.

Solution is credited to go to [Mateusz Dąbrowski](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/91679/mateusz-d%C4%85browski) [post](https://mateuszdabrowski.pl/docs/config/sfmc-behavioral-triggers/#1-ampscript-personalisation)